# parsing complex , multi level json response in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

that's my api response and I want to convert it to dart model and display all the response to the screen.. how can I achieve this in flutter ..I'm new to flutter.. how to parse object nested arrays ..like activityFieldValueList.attributeType.lookupValues.lookupValue. how can i do it in flutter ..though i can generate model from online json to dart converter ..i use ListVewBuilder but it's not working properly ..

```
{ "response":    [
       {
           "id": 3362,
           "moduleType": 1581,
           "projectId": 520,
           "planId": null,
           "isActive": 1,
           "gps": null,
           "deviceInfo": null,
           "activityFieldValueList": [
               {
                   "id": 23378,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672420229000,
                       "updatedOn": 1672400429000,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26407,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 13,
                           "typeName": "Link from other entities",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 17
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Product",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": 1572,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 1,
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [],
                       "dateAttributes": null,
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": null,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": null,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "725,726",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23379,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672420290000,
                       "updatedOn": 1672400491000,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26408,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 7,
                           "typeName": "Numeric",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 3
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Total Amount with Tax",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 2,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": null,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [],
                       "dateAttributes": null,
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": null,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": null,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "98988",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23380,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672420312000,
                       "updatedOn": 1672400513000,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26409,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 3,
                           "typeName": "Date",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 6
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Purchase Date",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 3,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": null,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [],
                       "dateAttributes": {
                           "id": 3241,
                           "stdLookupAttribute": null,
                           "previousDateAllowed": null,
                           "futureDateAllowed": null
                       },
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": null,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": null,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "2023-02-27",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23381,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672420372000,
                       "updatedOn": null,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26410,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 18,
                           "typeName": "Data List",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 18
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Partner Type",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 4,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": null,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [
                           {
                               "id": 10020,
                               "lookupValue": "Contractor",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 2,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": 9899,
                               "dataListId": 26237
                           },
                           {
                               "id": 10021,
                               "lookupValue": "Fabricator",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 3,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": 9900,
                               "dataListId": 26237
                           },
                           {
                               "id": 10022,
                               "lookupValue": "Mason",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 4,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": 9901,
                               "dataListId": 26237
                           }
                       ],
                       "dateAttributes": null,
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": 26237,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": 0,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "9900",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23382,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672420400000,
                       "updatedOn": null,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26411,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 18,
                           "typeName": "Data List",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 18
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "District",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 5,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": null,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [],
                       "dateAttributes": null,
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": 26025,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": 1,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "9681",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23383,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672418548000,
                       "updatedOn": 1672400624000,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26400,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 1,
                           "typeName": "Single Select Dropdown",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 4
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Partner",
                       "parentAttribId": 25920,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": {
                           "id": 25,
                           "name": "Select Company"
                       },
                       "mandatoryFlag": 1,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 0,
                       "displayOrder": 6,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": 0,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [],
                       "dateAttributes": {
                           "id": 3242,
                           "stdLookupAttribute": null,
                           "previousDateAllowed": null,
                           "futureDateAllowed": null
                       },
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": 0,
                       "parentDataListId": null,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": null,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "1856",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23384,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672420450000,
                       "updatedOn": 1672400651000,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26412,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 6,
                           "typeName": "Text (single-line)",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 1
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Purchased From",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 7,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": null,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [],
                       "dateAttributes": null,
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": null,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": null,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "XYZ",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23385,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1672420484000,
                       "updatedOn": 1672400684000,
                       "timeZone": null,
                       "utcDateTime": null,
                       "id": 26413,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 4,
                           "typeName": "Image",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 8
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Upload Invoice",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 1,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 8,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": null,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [],
                       "dateAttributes": null,
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": null,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": null,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": null
                   },
                   "projectId": 520,
                   "value": "",
                   "isActive": 1,
                   "createdBy": 107290,
                   "updatedBy": 107290,
                   "createdOn": 1677214902000,
                   "updatedOn": 1677214902000,
                   "dependentDataListAttributes": []
               },
               {
                   "id": 23386,
                   "attrib": {
                       "createdOn": 1676480195000,
                       "updatedOn": 1676480195000,
                       "timeZone": "IST",
                       "utcDateTime": [
                           2023,
                           2,
                           15,
                           11,
                           26,
                           35
                       ],
                       "id": 28253,
                       "attributeType": {
                           "id": 1,
                           "typeName": "Single Select Dropdown",
                           "isActive": 1,
                           "displayOrder": 4
                       },
                       "projectId": 520,
                       "attributeName": "Approval Status",
                       "parentAttribId": null,
                       "parentFormId": null,
                       "instructions": "",
                       "systemAttribute": null,
                       "mandatoryFlag": 0,
                       "characterType": 1,
                       "minCharacters": null,
                       "maxCharacters": null,
                       "allowBrowsing": 0,
                       "maxImagesAllowed": 0,
                       "numericValidationType": 0,
                       "minDigits": null,
                       "maxDigits": null,
                       "minNumber": null,
                       "maxNumber": null,
                       "status": 1,
                       "fieldSpec": 2,
                       "displayOrder": 9,
                       "hasUniqueValues": 0,
                       "moduleType": 1581,
                       "calculationFormula": null,
                       "dummyValueForCalculation": null,
                       "referenceDocumentUrl": null,
                       "documentType": "",
                       "isOptionsAlphabetically": 0,
                       "lookupValues": [
                           {
                               "id": 11088,
                               "lookupValue": "Pending",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 1,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": null,
                               "dataListId": null
                           },
                           {
                               "id": 11089,
                               "lookupValue": "L1 Approved",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 2,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": null,
                               "dataListId": null
                           },
                           {
                               "id": 11090,
                               "lookupValue": "L2 Approved",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 3,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": null,
                               "dataListId": null
                           },
                           {
                               "id": 11091,
                               "lookupValue": "Approved",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 4,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": null,
                               "dataListId": null
                           },
                           {
                               "id": 11092,
                               "lookupValue": "Rejected",
                               "stageId": null,
                               "isActive": 1,
                               "statusDisplayOrder": 5,
                               "projectId": null,
                               "dataListValueId": null,
                               "dataListId": null
                           }
                       ],
                       "dateAttributes": null,
                       "linkedUpdateFlag": null,
                       "parentDataListId": null,
                       "addDataListDependentFields": 0,
                       "showAllDataListValues": null,
                       "otpValidation": 0,
                       "decimalFlag": 0
                   }
               }
           ]
       }    
    ] 
}
```

Comment: Hi there, it would be great if you could focus on one question at a time. If you need to know how to access a specific item of a model, please consider editing your original question to reflect this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: https://quicktype.io/
May be 100% working.

Thanks for reading my answer.

Comment: yes .. i can make model with this ..but how can i access those nested arrays ..like activityFieldValueList.attributeType.lookupValues.lookupValue ... though it's not working inside of ListView.builder ..

Comment: If you have nested array. You can use nested listview builder. I mean 1 listview builder in 2 listview builder. If you need proper solution please comment me i will provide you. Because this qution is older now.